# Tweepy Client v2 Self?

Tags: python, twitter, typeerror, tweepy

This is my code:

```
tweepy.Client(bearer_token = bearerToken,
              consumer_key = consumerKey,
              consumer_secret = consumerSecret,
              access_token = accessToken,
              access_token_secret = accessTokenSecret)


tweepy.Client.create_tweet(text='if this worked this was tweeted from Python code', user_auth=True)
```

And this is the error that I keep receiving:

```
TypeError: create_tweet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

What am I missing? From what I can see on the tweepy.Client documentation there is no self positional argument to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Client.create_tweet` as a class method there instead of using your instance of `Client`.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, however I'm not sure how to fix this problem coding wise. What would the solution look like?

Comment: Assign your instance of `Client` to a variable and then use it instead of the class itself.